# google analytics is it possible to rename a screen that is used for tagging?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk, google-analytics-firebase

Is it possible to rename a screen that is used for tagging, but keep the historical data for the old name? I am using the Android SDK & iOS SDK.

I did not specify the screen manually, I used the automatic tracking function.

So for example I have a couple of years of data where a screen is called 'com.example.IntroActivity'. I now want to change that to say 'com.example.SplashActivity', but keep all of the previous data for IntroActivity.

Is there a good way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the screen name: [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/screens)

When you change the screen name, it will not affect historical data. You will just start to see the new name and the old name will stay as is.

Comment: Is there any way to merge with the previous record?

Comment: No, you cannot "merge". Data in GA is hit based. For every hit, numerous points of data are recorded. When you pull up a screen name, it is essentially searching through those hits and getting you all data associated with that screen name. When you change the name, it will be seen as a new page. What you can do is keep track of the two names and filter/report on both pages together.